# How to manage two coupled aggregates in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, dddd

I am developing Electric Vehicle Charging Station Management System, which is connected to several `Charging Station`s, and I am in  an impasse. In this domain, I've come up with an aggregate for the `Charging Station`, which includes the internal state of the `Charging Station`(whether it is connected, the internal state of its Connectors).

It has a `UnlockConnector` method, for which, to accurately respect its name(and not be anemic) it sends the request to the respective `Charging Station`, as it is central to my domain to know of the `Charging Station`'s connectivity, and to send requests to the physical `Charging Station`:

```golang
type Connector struct {
  Status string
}

type ChargingStation struct {
  Connected bool
  Connectors []Connector
  URL string
  ...
}

func (station *ChargingStation) UnlockConnector(connectorID int, stationClient service.StationClient) error {
  if !station.Connected {
    return errors.New("charging station is not connected")
  }
  connector := station.Connectors[connectorID]
  if connector.Status != "Available" {
    return errors.New("connector is not available to be unlocked")
  }
  err := stationClient.SendUnlockConnectorRequest(station.URL, connectorID)
  if err != nil {
    return errors.New("charging station rejected the request")
  }
  station.On(event.StationConnectorUnlocked{
    ConnectorID: connectorID,
    Timestamp: time.Now(),
  })
  return nil
}
```

And I've come up with another aggregate which represents the `Charging Session`, the interaction between a User and a `Charging Station`'s `Connector`. The creation of a `Charging Session` is entirely coupled with the `Connector`'s state, i.e. if the `Connector` has been unlocked by a user, a session was created, if the `Connector`'s energy flow has stopped, the `Charging Session` has ended.

However coupled they both are, the `Charging Session` entity doesn't seem to belong to the `Charging Station` Aggregate, as it doesn't respond to the primary question: when a Station is deleted, should its `Charging Session`s be deleted as well?) also, I when I would pay for the energy consumed in this session, it wouldn't have anything to do with the Station Aggregate Context.

I thought of creating a `SessionCreator` domain service that makes sure that when a `Charging Station`'s `Connector` is unlocked, a `Charging Session` is to be created as well:

```golang
type SessionCreator interface {
  CreateSession(station *station.Station, connectorID int, sessionID int) error
}

type sessionCreator struct {
  stationClient StationClient
}

type (svc sessionCreator) CreateSession(station *station.Station, connectorID int, userID string, sessionID int) error {
  err := station.UnlockConnector(connectorID, svc.stationClient)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  session.Create(sessionID, station.ID, connectorID, userID)
  return nil
}
```

However it just feels a little odd, and doesn't quite satisfy the other invariants(when a connector's energy flow stops, it must end the session), I though as well as making a Event Listener that listens to the `StationConnectorUnlocked` event, but I just don't know which would be the ideal way.

Comment: Are you running this model inside the charging station itself? or is the model running in some central location, listening to messages from charging stations?

Comment: i am running the model only in this central location, where it listens to messages from all charging stations. it's not possible to change the code of the charging stations itself, because they come already builtin with the vendor's code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand from the problem, I think that your aggregates `Charging Station` and `Charging Session` are correct. You say they are both coupled, but it seems to me that `Charging Station` doesn't need to know about the existence of the Session, and the Session doesn't really need to know anything about the internals of the Station, so the coupling to me is low.

Regarding your question about how to create and modify the Session when things happen on the Station, the solution seems clear to me based on your wording:

> if the **Connector has been unlocked** by a user, a **session was created**, if the **Connector's energy flow has stopped**, the **Charging Session has ended**.

The highlighted words are *business Events*. You could draw it like:

- ConnectorUnlocked --> ChargingSessionCreated
- ConnectorEnergyFlowStopped --> ChargingSessionEnded

And the way I'd implement this is with a pub/sub system, so aggregates publish events after a state change and subscribers trigger use cases, which might execute an operation on an aggregate, which will likely end up publishing an event.

The distributed nature of this approach makes it a bit more difficult to follow what is going on on the whole system as Unlocking the Connector and creating the Session don't happen in a single place. They will likely happen in two different parts of the system. The advantage is that over time, stakeholders can come up with many things that need to happen when the Connector is unlocked and you'll only have to keep adding subscribers to that existing event.

Comment: I've developed a process manager to listen to the Connector Events, and to raise Commands to the Session Aggregate(CreateSession, FinishSession). In the CreateSession command, everything works perfectly, as I simply do CreateSession(id: new UUID(), stationId: event.StationID, ...).  However, in the FinishSession, I can't load the Session Aggregate, to finish it, because the ConnectorEnergyFlowStopped event doesn't contain the Session ID in it.

Comment: I've managed to add an internal in-memory state to the process manager, so that it associates a (stationID, connectorID) with a (sessionID). However, as it is in-memory, as soon as the process manager crashes, I've lost the association between the (stationID, connectorID) <-> (sessionID) and I can no longer respond properly to the ConnectorEnergyFlowStopped event. Do you have any idea how should I handle that? Should I persist the Process Manager state? Should I persist it with Process Manager events(which would be awkward since, it does not correlate nicely with the Ubiquitous Language)

Comment: I don't understand why you need a process manager. The way I see the act of handling an event and executing an operation in an aggregate is a Use Case (in Clean Architecture) and the only thing it does is: var agg = uow.GetAggregateBySomeId(); agg.ExecuteOperation(); uow.Commit(). You can use UnitOfWork or Repository, but you'll define an interface specifically for that aggregate. So, in your case, you might need a GetSessionById and GetSessionByConnectorId. This should allow you to handle all asynchronous and synchronous operations on Sessions.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I'm gonna look into more deeply into these terms as I am not accostumed to them. But, as I'm implementing an event-sourced system, the only way I can get the event stream of a session, is by its ID, not by its ConnectorID(because I only know the session's ConnectorID when I hydrate it back), so I don't see how I could implement the GetSessionByConnectorId function. Am I missing something?

Comment: One way I could think of, would be to hydrate all sessions, and find the unfinished session with a given ConnectorID, but I assume that's not the canonical(and efficient) way to do it, right?

Comment: Ah well. I personally don't like event sourcing (I've always seen too many issues and little value to it), so I can't really help you with this, sorry. The easiest way to store aggregates is with documents (NoSQL) as you need to read and write them as a single unit anyway. Hydrating all sessions doesn't sound right as you'll eventually run into scalability problems. Maybe you'll have to post this one as a separate question and someone with ES knowledge can help you.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks for helping me in the other stuff though :)